# how to write 'list data' in a file using python logging.info module

Tags: python, list, logging

I am trying to log list data in a text file using python logging.info module.
I am able to see the logged data in my log text file but it always put the list data inside '(' ')'brackets. I am not able to understand the reason for it.

Please help me to understand it. Please bear if I am missing any obvious thing as I am a beginner in python.

Here is my code:

```
therapy = "log data:",":".join ("{:02x}".format(x) for x in respList[4:])

logging.info(therapy)

date = "Date:","/".join("{:02x}".format(a) for a in ts[:-4])

logging.info(date)

time = "Time:",":".join("{:02x}".format(a) for a in ts[3:6])#-3:

logging.info(time)
```

Here is the output in log text file:

```
2019-03-04 17:31:18,943 - 
('log data:','01:00:00:03:05:26:58:18:00:00:03:e8:00:00:32
:00:01:32:0e:00:c8:01:19:03:04:11:27:25:1c')
2019-03-04 17:31:18,943 - ('Date:', '19/03/04')
2019-03-04 17:31:18,943 - ('Time:', '11:27:25')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi people , Can you please help me out with this question ---> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718051/append-logs-using-filemode-a-does-not-work-properly-with-python-loggers-fil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just made a tuple `"string","string"` instead of make contatenation `"string"+"string"`

Comment: Thank you so much @MartinP ,

Comment: @sudha11 you can just mark answer as solution, if it solved your issue ;)

Answer (score 1):

By putting a comma between the two strings as a value for all of your assignments, you're assigning tuples to the variables, which, when passed the logger, would be formatted with parentheses around it because that's how the tuple's `__repr__` function formats it.

You can instead concatenate the two strings with the `+` operator, but put a space after the colon for better readability:

```
therapy = "log data: " + ":".join ("{:02x}".format(x) for x in respList[4:])
logging.info(therapy)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @blhsing , it worked !                                                               
                                                                                     

Here is the expected output after I changed the code as per suggestion:                   
    2019-03-05 12:46:38,207 - log data:02:00:a9:11:00:00:19:03:05:10:17:00